# how to create a watcher using fsevents in mac osx 10.6

Tags: macos, fsevents

I m trying to get file event notifications using fsevents.h file.

I m working with Mac OS X 10.6 and XCode 3.1.4 in which i found fsevents.h in four following locations

1. /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/FSEvents.h
2. /Xcode3.1.4/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers
3. /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers
4. /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers

I have following issues in accessing fsevents.h

1) Out of above four locations which one should be included since fsevents is not getting included unless i put following include syntax
    include<../../../../Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/fsevents.h>

2) Where could I find the function definition whose prototypes are declared in fsevents.h using "extern" keyword

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

For more info take a look at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html